# Php form emailing but $_POST['email'] is failing

Tags: javascript, php, email, post

I have a form on my site that I want to send an email on submit. The email gets sent but none of the content gets sent along with it. It seems that isset($_POST['email']) is failing.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="sponsorForm" name="sponsor" role="form">
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <label for="sponsorname">Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="sponsorname" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <label for="sponsoremail">Email</label>
         <input type="email" name="sponsoremail" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <label for="sponsormessage">Message</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="sponsormessage" rows="7" placeholder="Message...">
         </textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer" style="border: none;">                  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sponsor-thanks" id="sponsor-submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is some javascript to call the php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#sponsorForm").submit(function(event){
        submitSponsorForm();
        return false;
    });
});

function submitSponsorForm(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendSponsor.php",
        cache:false,
        data: $('form#sponsorForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            $("#sponsor").html(response)
            $("#sponsor-modal").modal('hide');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $sponsorname = strip_tags($_POST['sponsorname']);
    $sponsoremail = strip_tags($_POST['sponsoremail']);
   $sponsormessage = strip_tags($_POST['sponsormessage']);
    $message = "Name: ".$sponsorname."\r\nEmail: ".$sponsoremail."\r\nMessage: ".$sponsormessage; 
}
    mail("xxx@xxx.com", "subject", $message, "from: xxx");
?>
```

Comment: print_r($_POST) to check if it is getting any data or not.

Comment: Your email name is `sponsoremail` so check `$_POST['sponsoremail']`

Comment: You should also move `mail("xxx@xxx.com", "subject", $message, "from: xxx");` inside the braces. It's illogical to have the mail function send an email outside of the `if` clause since it's dependent on the values inside the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sponsoremail'])) {
        $sponsorname = strip_tags($_POST['sponsorname']);
        $sponsoremail = strip_tags($_POST['sponsoremail']);
       $sponsormessage = strip_tags($_POST['sponsormessage']);
        $message = "Name: ".$sponsorname."\r\nEmail: ".$sponsoremail."\r\nMessage: ".$sponsormessage; 
      mail("xxx@xxx.com", "subject", $message, "from: xxx");
     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your form, the name of your email input field is 'sponsoremail'

So you should use the name sponsoremail as the index of `$_POST` variable as `$_POST['sponsoremail']` to check if user fill the email or not but you have used `$_POST['email']` which is not found in your form.

Use `if (isset($_POST['sponsoremail']))` instead of `if (isset($_POST['email']))` and it should work.